# Running windows service made in Python blocking SQL Server table access from other applications

Tags: python, sql-server, windows, service

I have made an application in python which takes data from MQTT using paho library and store it in tables in SQL Server.

- When I run the code using `python filename.py`, its working fine.
- When I make exe file using pyinstaller and run, then also its working file.
- When I make it as a WINDOWS SERVICE and start, then it is working and storing data in MS SQL server tables but blocking some other applications like MS SQL server management studio, web application using asp.net (which is used to view data from same tables) from querying and getting timeout EXCEPT VS code with SQL Server extension.
- If I stop the windows service then immediately other applications are able to access the tables.
- When I remove INSERT statement for a particular table from python code and then running it as windows service, then it is not blocking that table access from other applications.

What could be the reason?

Update 1: When making windows service, database connection variable was made (by mistake) local to a class function instead of global as in normal console code but the cursor variable was still global. Making the connection variable again as global solved the problem. What difference was it creating?

Comment: I'd make sure to properly close the connection to the database when not needed, i.e., usually with a using block. When running in the console, your script exits, and the connection is closed automatically when your script exits. When running as a service, your script never closes, hence the database connection is left open.

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel but my script is using infinite loop so its not closing the connection when running in the console.

Comment: Without a single line of code to see it's only a guess, but based on your comment that removing the insert statement prevents the blocking, I'd wager that you're falling afoul of [Connection.autocommit](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#autocommit) being false by default. i.e.: you either need to set `Connection.autocommit=true` or you need to call `cursor.commit()` after each data-modifying statement.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, the problem was solved and is mentioned in the "Update 1:" but I do not understand how it solved. The commit statement is already there.